# Git working tree in IIS's wwwroot

Tags: git, iis, repository

We have a Visual Studio 2003 solution containing multiple web-applications that need to be located in `c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\`.

I know that I can create a repository in SVN that can contain those applications, and each physical path can be connected to a different location in the same repository. For ex:

- `c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\app1\`   >   `SVN-REPO:/apps/app1`
- `c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\app2\`   >   `SVN-REPO:/apps/app2`

I need to create this repository in GIT, so my questions are:

1. Is is possible to do this with git, because I want to avoid having the `.git` folder in `c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\` (we can have a similar configuration for a different project, and I'm pretty sure that two working trees can't share the same `.git` folder)?
2. Does anyone have a good idea on how to organize this repository in git?

Comment: Why do the paths need to be from the same repository?

Comment: Because sub-directories of wwwroot are separate (Visual Studio) projects, but a part of a single (Visual Studio) solution which is treated as a single product. And only that product has a version, so it makes sense to have all of this in a single repository. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because sub-directories of `wwwroot` are separate (Visual Studio) projects, but a part of a single (Visual Studio) solution which is treated as a single product.
>   And only that product has a version, so it makes sense to have all of this in a single repository. What would you suggest?

Even if [submodules](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) could help in theory, since you don't want a `.git` in `wwwroot`, the simplest solution remains:

- 1 git repo in `wwwroot` with both apps in it,
- but with the actual `.git` located elsewhere, and the `GIT_DIR` environment variable set to reference that external `.git` directory.

```
--git-dir=
```

> Set the path to the repository.
>   This can also be controlled by setting the `GIT_DIR` environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.